# $\chi$ Distribution for Rectified Gaussians

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, chi-squared

We know that a Chi distribution is the distribution of the root of the sum of $k$ squared independent Gaussian random variables $Z_i \sim N(0, 1)$:

$$ Y = \sqrt{\sum_{i=0}^k Z_i^2} $$.

If we have another random variable $Z^R_I$ which is a rectified Gaussian,
$$ Z_i^R = max(0, Z_i) $$,

Would it be possible to determine the Variance and Expected value for the distribution of the root of the sum of $k$ squared independent **rectified** Gaussian random variables $Z_i^R $ ?

$$ Y^R = \sqrt{\sum_{i=0}^k (Z_i^R)^2} $$
$$ E[Y^R]=   ? $$
$$ Var[Y^R]=   ? $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can give formulas, which are not totally closed.

First, the distribution of $Y^2$ is $\chi^2_k$, that is $\Gamma(d/2,1/2)$. The expectation of $Y^2$ is simple, $E[Y^2]=k$, but the expectation of $Y$ is not.
$$E[Y] = \int_0^\infty x^{1/2} \frac{x^{k/2-1}e^{-x/2}}{2^{k/2}\Gamma(k/2)} dx = 2^{1/2}\frac{\Gamma(k/2+1/2)}{\Gamma(k/2)} =: m_k.$$

Next, for each $i$, $P[Z_i^R>0]=1/2$ and the distribution of $(Z_i^R)^2$ given $Z_i^R>0$ equals the distribution of $Z_i^2$. By using the independence and the equidistribution of the $Z_i$, we derive that the distribution of the number $N$ of indexes $i$ such that $Z_i>0$ is a binomial random variable with parameters $k$ and $1/2$. Moreover, the distribution of $(Y^R)^2$ given $N=n$ is $\chi^2_n$.

Therefore, $E[(Y^R)^2|N] = N$ and $E[Y^R|N] = m_N$. Taking expectations, we get $E[(Y^R)^2] = EN = k/2$ and $$E[Y^R] = E[m_N] = \sum_{n=0}^k m_n{k \choose n}/2^k.$$

Comment: @Liam F-A Did you see the answer?